# While trying to update web reference. Custom tool msdiscocodegenerator failed

Tags: c#, asp.net

I was trying to migrate a web application from VS 2005 to VS 2012. Migration happened successfully. However when I tried to update the web reference in the project I get the error the below error and reference.cs is not generated. only wsdl,disco and .map files are generated.

"The custom tool 'MSDiscoCodeGenerator' failed. Object reference not set to an instance of an object.".

I tried removing the reference and adding it back but it continues to throw the same error.

I tried to create a new web application and added the web reference. It works fine here.

Could any one suggest what the problem might be?

Additionally I observed that I get this error If I have a web service setting of "URL Behavior" set to "Dynamic". If I set it to "static" I don't get this error and reference.cs file is generated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it resolved. After migration the .resx files were not migrated properly. This was throwing the error. I had to open .resx code, change the XSD schema to match that of 4.5, resheader version from 1.0 to 2.0, resheader reader and writer versions to 4.0. Then it helped. Also There were some invalid mime types got in the resx XML. I got rid of it and web references updated later

Answer (score 0):

Remove the reference from the project.

Then Expand Properties -> Settings.

If you're not using the settings file for anything then delete it.

Now try and add the reference again.

Comment: Thanks for the help. No removing the settings did not help :(

Comment: FYI ... I got it resolved. After migration the .resx files were not migrated properly. This was throwing the error. I had to open .resx code, change the XSD schema to match that of 4.5, resheader version from 1.0 to 2.0,  resheader reader and writer versions to 4.0. Then it helped. Also There were some invalid mime types got in the resx XML. I got rid of it and web references updated later.